# SSL VPN certificate issue

Tags: cisco-asa

We have situation for SSL VPN (CISCO ASA anyconnect )

VPN gateway- XXX.cap.org - 
wild card certificate (*.cap.org) is expiring on next month.

Anyconnect client is getting authenticated with AD not certificate, do we still need to worry for ANyConnect client? Will they get aunteticated with AD even certificate gets expire for VPN gateway (XXX.cap.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of my understanding,
unless you configured for certificate authentication, certificate is not used for user authentication.
the wild card certificate you are using will be presented by ASA to user while you access ssl portal ( like normal https access of web sites) or when you access through the client software.
Client will check the authenticity of certificate(whether it is signed by trusted CA/certificate is expired or not/common name is matching?..etc). so if your certificate is expired, error will be shown in user machine. user have to accept it then only they will be directed to the portal.